# UISearchBar in storyboard Xcode

Tags: uitableview, uisearchbar, uistoryboard

I want to create searchBar for my table in storyboard xcode, everythings works for me and I don't have any error, just search doesn't work.

I saw this two tutorial but still doesn't work. I cann't search.
my tutorial:

```
   -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897171/uisearchbar-implemented-with-storyboards
   -http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IqDZHgI_s24
```

would you please help me,
Thanks in Advance!

Here is my code

CreateViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CreateViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,       UISearchBarDelegate>
{
// @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
NSArray *datas;
NSMutableArray *displayItems;
IBOutlet UITableView * tableView;
IBOutlet UISearchBar * searchbar;
}

@end
```

CreateViewController.m

```
#import "CreateViewController.h"

@interface CreateViewController ()

@end

@implementation CreateViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

datas = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Johan", @"Paul",@"George",@"Ringo", nil];
displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:datas];
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [datas count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";//This is the identifier in storyboard    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [datas objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
-(void)searchbar:(UISearchBar *)searchbar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{
if([searchText length] == 0){
    [displayItems removeAllObjects];
    [displayItems addObjectsFromArray:datas];
}else{
    [displayItems removeAllObjects];
    for(NSString * string in datas){
        NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound){
            [displayItems addObject:string];   
        }
    }
}
[tableView reloadData];
}

 #pragma mark - Table view delegate

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
// Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
/*
 <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib    name#>" bundle:nil];
 // ...
 // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
 */
}

@end
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this tutorial iOS Quick Tip: Filtering a UITableView with a search bar

http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
if(text.length == 0)
{
    isFiltered = FALSE;
}
else
{
    isFiltered = true;
    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Food* food in allTableData)
    {
        NSRange nameRange = [food.name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange descriptionRange = [food.description rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredTableData addObject:food];
        }
    }
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: What if you have sections in your tableview? How can search work knowing that you'll be searching inside the contents of the sections instead of a single array?

Comment: jaytrixz, you might find my other tutorial on filtering a grouped UITableView useful. It uses a dictionary of arrays instead of a single array. http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/07/04/filtering-a-grouped-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/

Answer (score 1):

you can use NSPredicate for this function, modify your search delegate method as below

```
    [datas release];
datas = nil;

datas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: displayItems];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like[c] %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@*",searchBar.text]];
[datas filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
[tableView reloadData];
```

check the sample code here

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/SearchSample.zip

Comment: u might have used some other UISearchBar instance, replace with that name.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, you need to change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` to use the `displayItems` array rather than the datas array.
Also check if you have set the `UISearchBarDelegate` for your search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this,

- In your header file declare arrays like this,

  ```
  NSMutableArray *datas;
  NSMutableArray *displayItems;
  ```
- Then change array initializing in **viewDidLoad** like this,

  ```
  datas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Johan", @"Paul",@"George",@"Ringo", nil];
  displayItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:datas];
  ```
- Change the array in **cellForRowAt** method,

  ```
  cell.textLabel.text = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  ```
- Then print your search string inside **textDidChange** method using NSLog. If it is not printing, there's something wrong with the IBOutlet connection. If it prints, replace this method and see if it works,

  ```
  -(void)searchbar:(UISearchBar *)searchbar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText{

  if([searchText length] == 0){

  }else{
      [displayItems removeAllObjects];
      for (int i=0; i<[datas count]; i++) {
          if ([searchText hasPrefix:[datas objectAtIndex:i]]) {
              [displayItems addObject:[datas objectAtIndex:i]];
          } else {

          }
      }
  }
  [tableView reloadData];
  }
  ```

My sorting method is not the best in the world. But try to get your code to work.

**Edit**: I think your delegate doesn't fire. Try this method instead of the above.

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar*) theSearchBar
{
if([searchBar.text length] == 0){
arrayDisplayData = arrayOriginalData;
}else{
    [arrayDisplayData removeAllObjects];
    for(NSString * string in arrayOriginalData){
        NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:searchBar.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (r.location != NSNotFound){
            [arrayDisplayData addObject:string];   
        }
    }
}
[tblResults reloadData];
}
```

Or this,

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

Comment: Does your tableview shows the data you have put when you start the app?. I mean these, 
"datas = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Johan", @"Paul",@"George",@"Ringo", nil];"

Comment: @deamonsarea Thanks, I try it the second one didn't work and in the first one I have error searchBar.text and [tblResults reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you cellForRowAtIndexPath to use the displayItems array rather than the datas array

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";//This is the identifier in storyboard    
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [displayItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

And also change the numberOfRowsInSection to use the displayItems array count

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [displayItems count];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but Notthing happened